# How to get responsive of canvas paperjs view

Tags: responsive-design, paperjs, tokbox

I am using tokbox annotations. My functionality is working fine.

I am using https://github.com/aullman/opentok-whiteboard

But the problem is my canvas width is 880x520 in the web. But how to scale view size for mobiles? If I use 100% width on mobile devices. but how to match coordinates same on web and mobile devices.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do what you want is too rely on `Paper.js` built-in resize handling:

- add `resize` attribute to your `<canvas>` (see "Canvas Configuration" part in the [documentation](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/))
- setup an event handler callback as [view.onResize](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#onresize) value, to update your project accordingly to the new view size

```js
// setup paper
paper.setup('canvas');

// draw a circle at view center
var circle = new paper.Path.Circle({
  center: paper.view.center,
  radius: 50,
  fillColor: 'orange'
});

// when view is resized...
paper.view.onResize = function() {
  // ...log new view width
  console.log('view.width is now: ' + paper.view.bounds.width);
  // ...place circle at new view center
  circle.position = paper.view.center;
};

// draw instructions
new paper.PointText({
  content: 'Resize the window and see that view is automatically resized',
  point: paper.view.center.subtract(0, 80),
  justification: 'center'
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Scale canvas with resize attribute to full size */

canvas[resize] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.8/paper-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
```